# The flutter project cannot run IOS devices, but it can run Android devices,why?

Tags: flutter

I can't see what caused it. I hope I can get your help. Thank you.[image]

Comment: Have you run flutter doctor and seen that everything is passes?

Comment: Are you using Mac to build the IOS app?

Comment: No problem running  run flutter doctor

Comment: yes,I am used mac

Comment: enter `./ios` folder and run `pod install`. Try and see the output, it's the one you see in AS. I guess you are using a library that needs Pods,`Cocoapods` is one of default library dependency (along with `Carthage`). But something is wrong, you need to figure out why pods have errors.

Comment: Specifically you have a problem with `MTBBarcodeScanner`. See the `./ios/Podfile` (you can also post it on your question so we could see it) and try figuring out what's the problem with this pod dependency

Comment: The reason why on Android all is fine, is because the flutter library you are using on the Android side acts different rather than on iOS side. On iOS side, as I said before, talks to the native layer using a library added with pods. And this has errors.

Comment: I found the reason. My pod library is in trouble. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Posted my comments as an answer so that you can upvoted and falg it as accepted, if you like. So to have come good feedback on my help ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185248/discussion-between-shadowsheep-and-).

Comment: please change the image into text, so that search engines can find.

Answer (score 0):

Enter `./ios` folder and run `pod install`. Try and see the output, it's the one you see in AS. I guess you are using a library that needs `Pods`.

`Cocoapods` is one of default library dependency tool (along with `Carthage`).

Flutter uses `Cocoapods`.

The reason why on Android all is fine, is because the flutter library you are using on the Android side acts different rather than on iOS side.

On iOS side, as I said before, talks to the native layer using a library added with pods. And this has errors.

Here something is wrong, you need to figure out why pods have errors.

Specifically you have a problem with `MTBBarcodeScanner`.

See the `./ios/Podfile` (you can also post it on your question so we could see it) and try figuring out what's the problem with this pod dependency.